# Cleaner method to assign variables in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following code

```
 const lower = U => U.toLowerCase();

 const A = lower('A')
 const B = lower('B')
 const C = lower('C')
 const D = lower('D')
 ...
```

How do I represent this is a cleaner way? It is guaranteed that the variable name and parameter passed to the function are the same.

One possible solution I could think of is

```
const [ A, B, C, D ] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map(lower)
```

Is there a solution without this duplication?

Comment: So, are you trying to get all lowercase letters in an elegant way?

Comment: Why is there a problem? What's the matter with the current implementation?

Comment: Why do you need the variables anyway? Can't you just keep chaining and do what you need? Dynamic variables are no good...

Comment: Well, when I need to add another variable I need to make two changes. One use case I need this for it using internationalization. 

For eg,
**const ERROR_MSG = chrome.i18n.getMessage('ERROR_MSG')**

Comment: why not use an object with the former variable names as keys. it would be easy to maintain and to iterate.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thats sounds reasonable, can you give a code snippet?

Comment: `const [ A, B, C, D ] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map(function(e){return e.toLowerCase()})`

Comment: You cannot do anything if you want A, ... to be local variables. There are no variable variables in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with the former variable names as keys. It is easy to maintain and to iterate.

```js
const lower = U => U.toLowerCase(),
      object = {};

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].forEach(c => object[c] = lower(c));

console.log(object);
```

With given values inside of the object

```js
const lower = U => U.toLowerCase(),
      object = { A: 'A', B: 'B', C: 'C', D: 'D' };

Object.keys(object).forEach(k => object[k] = lower(object[k]));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score -1):

This has turned out to be a "very" intriguing question for me and it helped me to comprehend something deeper in JavaScript (not completely though). OK long story short you can do as follows;

```js
var f = String.prototype.toLowerCase,
    r = [];

r = ["A", "B", "C", "D"].map(f.call,f);
console.log(r);
```

Here we are providing the `this` as the `String.prototype.toLowerCase` function itself. However this is a slightly (or not slightly) a tricky matter.

When you try the callback function of `.map()` isolated from the `.map()` by passing the same arguments everything works just fine as follows;

```js
var c = String.prototype.toLowerCase.call("A",0,["A", "B", "C", "D"]);
console.log(c); // <- "a";
```

However if you apply exactly the same function in a `.map()` it will throw  an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" error as follows;

```js
r = ["A", "B", "C", "D"].map(String.prototype.toLowerCase.call);
```

Hmm... seems like within `.map()` we have to provide `this` as `String.prototype.toLowerCase` function object itself. Why so..? Honestly beats me. May be someone can help...

Comment: Why? Because `call`, like any other method, is just an unbound function when you pass it.

Comment: @Bergi Great.. Just no different than `r = ["A", "B", "C", "D"].map(Function.call, String.prototype.toLowerCase);` Thank you.